# Magnetism due to relativity?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

So I have been reading in some books that magnetism does not have to be assumed a priori, but can be obtained from the electric field + special relativity.
And I have seen how this leads to the common formula for the magnetic field of a current carrying wire.

Fine.

What about materials that are inherently magnetic? Such as iron, or magnetite?

Surely their magnetic field is not a consequence of relativity? (if yes, who's moving and with respect to whom?)

Comment: This explains the concept nicely, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0

Comment: That video explains what the OP is *fine* with, not about inherently magnetic objects.

Comment: Just remember that atoms have electrons that are moving in their orbitals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetism in ferromagnetic materials (e.g. iron) emerge from the spin alignment of valence electrons.  [Spin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_%28physics%29) is a purely quantum phenomenon that occurs due to relativity, so without relativity one would not have spin in the first place.  The presence of spin causes electrons to possess an intrinsic magnetic moment, equal to [approximately twice the spin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio#Gyromagnetic_ratio_for_an_isolated_electron) (this factor can actually be derived from relativistic quantum field theory).

Answer (score 0):

Oliver Heaviside showed that magnetic fields are a result of moving charges, and that relativity is not really needed.  He showed that if gravity moves at a finite speed, then a magnetic like effect arises.

Bohr's atom is non-relativistic, but still has the correct magnetic properties.

Relativity itself is due to the failure to observe the etherfer, and that the speed of electric and gravitational field, might be more to the nature of the medium than the fields themselves.

Comment: I'm certainly not an expert on the history of physics, but I'm pretty sure that Orsted was the first one to discover that the motion of electric charge produces a magnetic field.

Comment: Heaviside showed that the magnetic field was due to the finite speed of the electric field, and that if gravity moves at a finite speed a similar gravitomagnetism asises.